# Re Initaite the last failed request after refresh token is provided

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, angular-http-interceptors

I have my angular 4 application which sends multiple request at the same time one after another to the API which is protected by OAuth2, I m facing issue when the request fails with 401 status code,I need to generate a new access token and re initiate the same request to the API and return the response to the method which is waiting for it. 
1- All the request fails one after another - so in order to hold other request to proceed i have added a loop which holds the request coming to the server when the token generation is in progress
2- To initiate the request I added the line `next.handle(request)` again in the block but was not working, then i tried calling `this.intercept(request,next)` method even then it was not working, after that the last approach i added was to re handle the request in the error block so now the code of the intercept method looks as below, but then i realized that the request is not even processed further even if i retry to handle the request. There are several tutorial simply suggesting `next.handle(request)`, but in my case it does not works as expected.
Only I was successful in handling the requests which comes after the failed request because till then the new access token is generated but the request which was failed simply drops.

Please see the code flow in the [link](https://gist.github.com/aqureshi536/14f5e5a273f875fbfc68ffa99729c99f)!

I have already spent a lot of time on debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this with by adding `Observable.fromPromise` in the intercept method and then calling a method that returns promise and the method was recursively called until I get the refresh token, but adding a delay in between every call so that I don't end up calling recursively several times.

Please refer this [link](https://gist.github.com/aqureshi536/cc5c4df7826d7488bda8c4fc5c7e9065) for the my code.
Please comment if facing any issues .

Reference : https://www.illucit.com/en/angular/angular-5-httpinterceptor-add-bearer-token-to-httpclient-requests/

Comment: I've changed the approach and removed the timeout section which results in failure of all the simultaneous request but the token is refreshed and all the subsequent request those were initiated and failed are re initiated