# Refreshing access token with multiple requests

Tags: axios, vuex, interceptor

Im struggling with getting axios interceptors to work.

When my token expires, i need it to refresh the access token and retry the original request once the token is refreshed.
I have this part working.

The problem is if i have concurrent api calls it will only retry the first request when the token was first invalid.

Here is my interceptor code:

```
    export default function execute() {
  let isRefreshing = false

  // Request
  axios.interceptors.request.use(
    config => {
      var token = Storage.getAccessToken() //localStorage.getItem("token");
      if (token) {
        console.log('Bearer ' + token)
        config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
      }
      return config
    },
    error => {
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
  )

  // Response
  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
      return response
    },
    error => {
      const originalRequest = error.config
      // token expired
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        console.log('401 Error need to reresh')

        originalRequest._retry = true

        let tokenModel = {
          accessToken: Storage.getAccessToken(),
          client: 'Web',
          refreshToken: Storage.getRefreshToken()
        }
        //Storage.destroyTokens();
        var refreshPath = Actions.REFRESH

        if (!isRefreshing) {
          isRefreshing = true

          return store
            .dispatch(refreshPath, { tokenModel })
            .then(response => {
              isRefreshing = false
              console.log(response)
              return axios(originalRequest)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              isRefreshing = false
              console.log(error)
              // Logout
            })
        } else {
          console.log('XXXXX')
          console.log('SOME PROBLEM HERE') // <------------------
          console.log('XXXXX')
        }
      } else {
        store.commit(Mutations.SET_ERROR, error.response.data.error)
      }
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
  )
}
```

I'm not sure what i need in the else block highlighted above.

EDIT:

When I do

```
return axios(originalRequest)
```

in the else block it works, however im not happy with the behaviours. It basically retries all the requests again and again until the token is refreshed.
I would rather it just retried once  after the token had been refreshed 
Any ideas

Thanks

Comment: What if your unset the token on the first request fail due to expire and then put all the next requests in some queue until token is refreshed. When token is refreshed, process the queue.

Answer (score 1):

You can just have additional interceptor which can refresh token and execute your pending requests.

In this, `countDownLatch` class can help.
Here is sample Interceptor code,

```
class AutoRefreshTokenRequestInterceptorSample() : Interceptor {

    companion object {
        var countDownLatch = CountDownLatch(0)
        var previousAuthToken = ""

        const val SKIP_AUTH_TOKEN = "SkipAccessTokenHeader"
        const val AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_KEY"
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response? {
        val request = chain.request()

        if (shouldExecuteRequest(request)) {

            // Execute Request
            val response = chain.proceed(request)

            if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                // Failed Case
                val errorBody = response.peekBody(java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE).string()
                val error = parseErrorModel(errorBody)

                // Gives Signal to HOLD the Request Queue
                countDownLatch = CountDownLatch(1)

                handleError(error!!)

                // After updating token values, execute same request with updated values.
                val updatedRequest = getUpdatedRequest(request)

                // Gives Signal to RELEASE Request Queue
                countDownLatch.countDown()

                //Execute updated request
                return chain.proceed(updatedRequest)
            } else {
                // success case
                return response
            }
        }

        // Change updated token values in pending request objects and execute them!
        // If Auth header exists, and skip header not found then hold the request
        if (shouldHoldRequest(request)) {
            try {
                // Make this request to WAIT till countdown latch has been set to zero.
                countDownLatch.await()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            // Once token is Updated, then update values in request model.
            if (previousAuthToken.isNotEmpty() && previousAuthToken != "newAccessToken") {
                val updatedRequest = getUpdatedRequest(request)
                return chain.proceed(updatedRequest)
            }
        }

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }

    private fun handleError(error: ErrorDto) {
        // update your token as per your error code logic
        //Here it will make new API call to update tokens and store it in your local preference.
    }

    /***
     * returns Request object with updated token values.
     */
    private fun getUpdatedRequest(request: Request): Request {
        var updateAuthReqBuilder: Request.Builder = request.newBuilder()
        var url = request.url().toString()

        if (url.contains(previousAuthToken.trim()) && previousAuthToken.trim().isNotEmpty()) {
            url = url.replace(previousAuthToken, "newAccessToken")
        }
        updateAuthReqBuilder = updateAuthReqBuilder.url(url)
        // change headers if needed
        return updateAuthReqBuilder.build()
    }

    private fun shouldExecuteRequest(request: Request) =
            shouldHoldRequest(request) && isSharedHoldSignalDisabled()

    /**
     * If count down latch has any value then it is reported by previous request's error signal to hold the whole pending chain.
     */
    private fun isSharedHoldSignalDisabled() = countDownLatch.count == 0L

    private fun shouldHoldRequest(request: Request) = !hasSkipFlag(request) && hasAuthorizationValues(request)

    private fun hasAuthorizationValues(request: Request) = isHeaderExist(request, AUTHORIZATION_HEADER)

    private fun hasSkipFlag(request: Request) = isHeaderExist(request, SKIP_AUTH_TOKEN)


    private fun isHeaderExist(request: Request, headerName: String): Boolean {
        return request.header(headerName) != null
    }

    private fun parseErrorModel(errorBody: String): Error? {
        val parser = JsonParser()

        // Change this logic according to your requirement.
        val jsonObject = parser.parse(errorBody).asJsonObject
        if (jsonObject.has("Error") && jsonObject.get("Error") != null) {
            val errorJsonObj = jsonObject.get("Error").asJsonObject
            return decodeErrorModel(errorJsonObj)
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun decodeErrorModel(jsonObject: JsonObject): Error {
        val error = Error()
       // decode your error object here
        return error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do:

```
let isRefreshing = false;
let failedQueue = [];

const processQueue = (error, token = null) => {
  failedQueue.forEach(prom => {
    if (error) {
      prom.reject(error);
    } else {
      prom.resolve(token);
    }
  });
  failedQueue = [];
};

axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    error => {
      const originalRequest = error.config;
      if (error.response.status === 400) {
        // If response is 400, logout
        store.dispatch(logout());
      }
      // If 401 and I'm not processing a queue
      if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
        if (isRefreshing) {
          // If I'm refreshing the token I send request to a queue
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            failedQueue.push({ resolve, reject });
          })
            .then(() => {
              originalRequest.headers.Authorization = getAuth();
              return axios(originalRequest);
            })
            .catch(err => err);
        }
        // If header of the request has changed, it means I've refreshed the token
        if (originalRequest.headers.Authorization !== getAuth()) {
          originalRequest.headers.Authorization = getAuth();
          return Promise.resolve(axios(originalRequest));
        }

        originalRequest._retry = true; // mark request a retry
        isRefreshing = true; // set the refreshing var to true

        // If none of the above, refresh the token and process the queue
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          // console.log('REFRESH');
          refreshAccessToken() // The method that refreshes my token
            .then(({ data }) => {
              updateToken(data); // The method that sets my token to localstorage/Redux/whatever
              processQueue(null, data.token); // Resolve queued
              resolve(axios(originalRequest)); // Resolve current
            })
            .catch(err => {
              processQueue(err, null);
              reject(err);
            })
            .then(() => {
              isRefreshing = false;
            });
        });
      }

      return Promise.reject(error);
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the schema of your token (after decrypted) but one of the attributes which is a good practice to keep is the exp "expiration_date".
Said so, having the expiration date you can know when you should refresh your token.

Without understanding your architecture is hard to inform the right solution. But let's say you are doing everything manually, usually onIdle/onActive is when we check if the user session is still ok, so at this time you could use the token info to know if you should refresh its value.

It is important to understand this process because the token should be refreshed only if the user is constantly active and it is about to expire (like 2min before).

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to angular version of the code for which i was facing the same problem and after changing many approaches this was my final code which is working at its best.

[Re Initaite the last failed request after refresh token is provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55609728/re-initaite-the-last-failed-request-after-refresh-token-is-provided/55614842#55614842)